# knockoutjs - when input is focused, put value in other spot

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I've looked through the KnockoutJS site and haven't found anything describing how to do this.  I have a table of rows of inputs that are all knockout observables.  When the focus is in the first or second column on any row, I was to grab that value in that input and stick it into a different spot on the page.  And then I also want to grab the value in the next input over to the right and stick that next to the previous value elsewhere on the page.  The two copied values are going into another table on the page.

Here is my first table with all the knockout observables:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: items">
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" data-bind="value: itemNo, insertPress: $index, deletePress: $index, hasFocus: invalidItemNum, selected: invalidItemNum, event: { blur: function(){ $parent.checkItemNo($data, $index); } }, attr: { name: 'sellerItems[' + $index() + '].itemNo', id: 'sellerItems_' + $index() + '__itemNo', tabindex: 4 + $index()}" class="form-control" /></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" data-bind="value: qty, insertPress: $index, tabEnterPress: '#tallyEntry', deletePress: $index, event: { blur: function(){ $parent.calcTotal($data); } }, attr: { name: 'sellerItems[' + $index() + '].qty', id: 'sellerItems_' + $index() + '__qty', tabindex: 5 + $index() }" class="form-control" />
                        <input type="hidden" data-bind="value: locCode, attr: { name: 'sellerItems[' + $index() + '].locationCode', id: 'sellerItems_' + $index() + '__locationCode' }" />
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="text" data-bind="value: price, attr: { name: 'sellerItems[' + $index() + '].retail', id: 'sellerItems_' + $index() + '__retail' }" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" tabindex="-1" /></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" data-bind="value: bro, attr: { name: 'sellerItems[' + $index() + '].brocCode', id: 'sellerItems_' + $index() + '__brocCode' }" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" tabindex="-1" />
                        <input type="hidden" data-bind="value: broID, attr: { name: 'sellerItems[' + $index() + '].brochureId', id: 'sellerItems_' + $index() + '__brochureId' }" />
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="text" data-bind="value: desc, attr: { name: 'sellerItems[' + $index() + '].itemDesc', id: 'sellerItems_' + $index() + '__itemDesc' }" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" tabindex="-1" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" data-bind="value: total, attr: { name: 'sellerItems[' + $index() + '].total', id: 'sellerItems_' + $index() + '__total' }" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" tabindex="-1" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" data-bind="value: seq, attr: { name: 'sellerItems[' + $index() + '].itemRow', id: 'sellerItems_' + $index() + '__itemRow' }" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" tabindex="-1" /></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
```

And here is the second table where I want the itemNo and qty copied into when itemNo or qty receive focus:

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="easyGlanceTable">
  <thead>
    <tr><th width="50%">Item No.</th><th>Qty</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you simply bind the second table's cells to the same observables?

Comment: @JasonSpake, that is what I orinally thought.  But how does it know which value to grab because every row has an item number and qty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could add `data-bind="hasFocus: inputSelected"` to your input, then add

```
self.inputSelected.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    console.log("input value is " + self.inputValue());
});
```

to your view model, which will fire everytime `inputSelected` changes

Comment: I already have a `hasFocus: invalidItemNum`.  Can I subscribe to that just like you suggested?

Comment: yes, from your vm, add `invalidItemNum.subscribe()` and define the function that will fetch and fill values